# ASP.Net Postback Broke After Changing Form Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net form which looks like the following when rendered (many lines of markup removed for brevity):

```
<form onsubmit="document.body.style.cursor='wait';showLoader();" action="mypage.aspx">
<!-- form elements and controls -->
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In `mypage.aspx.cs`'s `Page_Load` I am doing:

```
if(Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Foo();
} else {    
    Bar();
}
Quux();
```

Without modifying the HTML page using the Chrome Dev Tools, if I submit the form it executes `Bar()`. But If I removed or replaced the `onsubmit` attribute in the form with my own, ASP.Net thinks that the page is doing a post back and executes `Foo()`.

I find this behavior weird because the inline JS code in `onsubmit` does not change anything related to the form submission. Its function is only to add a loading GIF while the form is reloading. Could there be something I am missing here?

Comment: Is this form in an updatePanel or something?

Comment: No, it's inside a plain old body tag.

Comment: I'm confused.  My understanding is that the default asp.net behavior is to do a full postBack by default. But you say that you don't get the postBack unless you play with the onsubmit event of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a `submit` button, try adding a regular button, and call your gif functionality from it:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.body.style.cursor='wait';showLoader();" value="Click Me" />
```

This will not post anything, which is what you want. `<input type='submit'>` will always cause a postback, unless you cancel it with JavaScript.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0gd8t7ew/